# Airflow KubernetesOperator Error: `Invalid connection configuration. Options kube_config_path, kube_config, in_cluster are mutually exclusive`

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod, airflow-scheduler, kubernetespodoperator

I am pulling my dags from github using git-sync. The only changes I made to my values.yaml file was using `KubernetesExecutor`, configuring git-sync and logs.

Is there something else missing because when I run my dag, it fails and I get the following error messages.

`Creating pod load-weather-data-63b8f20d51e14ae4b0838c2e1c43c259 with labels: {'dag_id': 'hello-generic-world-0802134835', 'task_id': 'Load_weather_data', 'run_id': 'scheduled__2022-08-01T0000000000-4f8c0f359', 'kubernetes_pod_operator': 'True', 'try_number': '1'}`

`INFO - Deleting pod: load-weather-data-63b8f20d51e14ae4b0838c2e1c43c259`

`ERROR - Invalid connection configuration. Options kube_config_path, kube_config, in_cluster are mutually exclusive. You can only use one option at a time.`

Answer (score 0):

When you switched to `KubernetesExecutor`, you configured airflow to connect to the K8S cluster, and before that, you had other K8S configuration used by the operator `KubernetesPodOperator` to create pods on the cluster. So now, when the operator try to get the k8s_conn, it finds two different configurations (probably they are identical but they are different for the operator), and it raises this exception ([src code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/hooks/kubernetes.py#L172-L192)).

Try to delete old configurations and let the operator automatically use the executor configurations.

Comment: I ran ```kubectl config view``` and saw that I have 2 configs. I ran 


```kubectl config unset contexts.docker-desktop``` and 
```kubectl config unset clusters.docker-desktop```

I currently have just ```kind-airflow-cluster``` which is the current context. But when I trigger the dags, I get the same errror.